# Sketch the complex image of $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $$D=\{z:0 \le \Re(z)\le2 \}$$ and $$f(z)=(1+i)z + (1-2i).$$ Determine and sketch $f(D)$.

**My attempt:**

Let $z = x_0 + iy$ where $0\le x_0\le 2$.

Now \begin{align}f(z) &= f(x_0+iy) \\ &= (1+i)(x_0+iy) +(1-2i) \\ &= x_0 +ix_0 +iy -y +1 -2i \\ &= (x_0-y+1) + i(x_0 +y -2)\end{align}

I am stuck with the sketching of $f(D)$.

What I do know is the following:

If $x_0=0$ then $f(z) = (-y+1) + i(y-2)$ and

If $x_0=2$ then $f(z) = (-y+3) +iy$

I can also see that the region $f(D)$ will still be linear (since both the real and imaginary components are linear). Can anyone please show me how to sketch it?

Comment: Hint: Convert $1+i$ into polar coordinates. What does multiplication by a complex number do to points in $D$? How about translation by a constant?

Comment: @JohnDouma - So, essentially, the final region will be the region between two lines of gradient $-1$ that passes through the points $x=1$ and $x=2\sqrt{2}+1$ on the real axis?

Comment: I haven't calculated it but that sounds right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $f$ is a scaling (from the origin with factor $|1+i|=\sqrt2$) followed by a rotation (about the origin and of angle $\arg(1+i)=\pi/4$) followed by a translation (with vector $(1,-2)$).

Comment: So, essentially, the final region will be the region between two lines of gradient $-1$ that passes through the points $x=1$ and $x=2\sqrt{2}+1$ on the real axis?

Comment: @DJS, something like that, yes, but I didn't check the numbers you gave.